# My CSS coding is not reflecting on my pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WordPress and making my WooCommerce website. To the appearance, whenever I add additional CSS, as soon as I click to paste or write CSS code, a box appears with a long list of options like body-align, background, etc. When I enter the CSS code it has no effect on my pages. I can't see the changes. Please help.

Comment: can you share your code. so that we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: Without seeing your "code", I can only advise you to refresh web cache. It might helps you see your change

Comment: We need to see your code so we can understand the issue. I'm not really much of a WordPress person myself, but could you check the HTML? Make sure your <link> tag is in the <head> & </head> tags and has the correct file path for your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

**Temp solution:**

If you have problem with that the CSS is not read, even if you do change in CSS, one solution is add **?rnd=1** at the end of CSS link. This will be treated as a separate attempt to read CSS but fetches the same CSS source file. You can continue to step up the value 1. This is of course not solving the root cause of your problem but might work as a temp solution until you solve the problem permanently.

```
Syntax: [link to css]?rnd=1

Example: <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css?rnd=1">
```

**Troubleshooting:**

**Other things to consider/check/test:**

- Is your syntax of HTML and CSS correct? (take help of online checks if you are unsure how to check for syntax).
- If you create another CSS file and connect from HTML, does it work then?
- If you add the style inline, inside the HTML with style-tags, does the layout change?
- Control with different browsers if the error is persistent.

**If you still having problems:**

- Create new minimalistic HTML file and CSS file. Confirm that the connection between HTML and CSS works.
- If you cannot isolate the root cause, lift in the content from the broken files (HTML/CSS) into the new HTML/CSS files, but do it step by step, portions so you can control during the move, when and if the code breaks also in the new HTML/CSS files.

Comment: Is this a WordPress solution? This answer may help but not through the WordPress way.

Comment: You are again following the wrong point. I am not the Question poster :)